# Problem with precise age calculation in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to aggregate documents from my collection called 'users' based on the age of each user. For that, I've used $dateDiff aggregation operator, which returns the difference between two dates in years, months, weeks etc. In my 'users' collection, each document has a 'dateOfBirth' field (Date format), so to calculate the actual age of each 'user' I need to find the difference between their birth date and current date in years. But this $dateDiff does it in its own strange way...

For example:

```
"age": { $dateDiff: {
        startDate: new Date("2001-12-08T16:00:00.000+00:00"),
        endDate: new Date(),
        unit: "year"
      }}
```

**and this gives a result of 22**.

As the docs say, *"The $dateDiff expression returns the integer difference between the startDate and endDate measured in the specified units. Durations are measured by counting the number of times a unit boundary is passed. For example, two dates that are 18 months apart would return 1 year difference instead of 1.5 years."*

**When I set 'month' as a unit, the above example results as 257. 257 divided by 12 is 21,41. 21 whole year units.**

Another example:

```
"age": { $dateDiff: {
        startDate: new Date("1978-04-02T16:00:00.000+00:00"),
        endDate: new Date(),
        unit: "year"
      }}
```

the result is 45, and in months its 541. 541/12 = 45,08. Correct, I assume?

**Does anybody have an idea why this might be happening?
And are there any other options to achieve precise results with calculating age based on a birth date?**

Comment: The results I provide are correct. In fact, I'm not the only one who's reported on this problem: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/datediff-aggregation-behavior-mismatch/208428/3